# Exceeding the maximum volume on a Mac

Tags: osx, audio

Often I am listening to a recording on Mac that has been recorded to be soft. That means that even if I turn up the volume on the application and on Mac system settings the volume is still too soft. Is there any software that can allow me to exceed this limit? (ie. I don't believe that the limit is the computer's speakers, just the volume of the sound recording).

Comment: Which application are you currently using to listen to recordings? If you use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/), it will permit you to alter the maximum volume to something absurd by following [these instructions](https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/1r53t2/lpt_vlcs_maximum_volume_went_from_200_to_125/).

Comment: Are you using headsets? Get an amplifier.  If the issue is only this particular recording, well, never mind.

Comment: @Iwillnotexist I do often use VLC, so that's useful, but I'm looking to do it fit Chrome at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest giving [Boom 2](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom) a try - it boosts the sound output system-wide as and when you require, and can be fine-tuned with presets and equaliser controls. There's a trial version available on their website, and it is reasonably priced.

Comment: I wonder if there is an alternative (free of charge) to do this.

Comment: There are no free-of-charge alternatives that I'm aware of - the only other options I can find are [Hear](https://www.prosofteng.com/hear/) and [Bongiovi DPS](http://dpsplugin.com/home/), both of which actually cost more than Boom 2. I've not tried either of the other two, so I can't really tell you how they compare.

Comment: I brought boom 1 right before Yosemite came out. but now, with El Captain the boom lost his utility (not working anymore, the sound volume control). I really don't want the go back to boom2 after my first experience... (I didn't open a question because I think is best to increment this one)

Comment: Ah, sorry to hear that, @michel. I tried out Boom 2 back when I was still on Yosemite, but removed it because I did the upgrade to El Capitan. From their [feature comparison page](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom/features-comparison) it looks like Boom 2 **should** be compatible with El Capitan. Only way to find out for sure would be to download the trial version.